# I want to create a "Show More/Show Less" toggle button using Javascript and CSS, inside of a notion database

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, notion

I'm trying to use a 3rd party web development tool (based on notion) to create a "Show More/Show Less" button inside of a notion database. The interface for this tool has **Head, Body and CSS **sections for me to add code to update the website.

In terms of logic flow, I'm trying to have the Javascript code look at the row height for the text in the 3rd column of my database, and if the row height exceeds 120px, then the Javascript will first limit the height to 120px (maxHeight = 120px, overflow = Hidden), and then add a toggle button ("Show More"). This button can be clicked to show the overflowing text (overflow = None), and the toggle button changes to ("Show Less").

If the Javascript code looks at the row height and it is less than 120px, then the text and in the cell is treated as normal, and no button shows up.

My Javascript code I've been using is as follows (it doesn't work...)

```
<script>
// Wait until the Notion page has loaded before running the code
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Find all cell content elements with the appropriate selector
  const cellContents = document.querySelectorAll('.notion-table-view-cell.text ');

  cellContents.forEach(function (cellContent) {
    // Calculate the height of the cell content
    const cellHeight = cellContent.scrollHeight;

    // Check if the cell content height is greater than 120px
    if (cellHeight > 120) {
      // Create the "Show More" toggle button
      const toggleButton = document.createElement("button");
      toggleButton.textContent = "Show More";
      toggleButton.classList.add("show-more-button");

      // Set the initial maxHeight of the cell content element
      cellContent.style.maxHeight = "120px";
      cellContent.style.overflow = "hidden";

      // Append the toggle button before the cell content
      cellContent.appendChild(toggleButton);

      // Add a click event listener to toggle the content
      toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        // Toggle the maxHeight and overflow properties of the cell content element
        if (cellContent.style.maxHeight === "none" || cellContent.style.maxHeight === "") {
          cellContent.style.maxHeight = "120px";
          cellContent.style.overflow = "hidden";
          toggleButton.textContent = "Show More";
        } else {
          cellContent.style.maxHeight = "none";
          cellContent.style.overflow = "visible";
          toggleButton.textContent = "Show Less";
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

My CSS code is as follows (this seems to work - the "Show More" button shows up at the end of the text on all cells in the 3rd column of the database):

```
/* Style the "Show more" and "Show less" buttons */
.notion-collection-table__cell.text:nth-child(3)::after {
  content: "Show more";
  display: block;
  color: blue; /* Adjust the button color as needed */
  cursor: pointer;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white; /* Set the background color to match your cell background */
  padding: px 10px; /* Adjust padding as needed */
  border: 0px solid blue; /* Add a border to the button */
  border-radius: 5px; /* Add rounded corners to the button */
  z-index: 1; /* Ensure the button appears above the text */
}
```

I'm trying to get the Javascript to work, but given my limited background in web dev, I don't really know what could be going wrong. Any solutions to this would be much appreciated!

Things I've tried:

- playing around with the selector in the Javascript (I have a suspicion that this might be the issue - but don't know how to find the right selector to make sure the javascript is referencing the right content within the database). I've had no success with this, there are no changes to the webpage/notion database. The row height is not altered depending on the length of the text, and the "Show More" button is present, but clicking on it has no impact.
- a different approach - first limiting row height in the CSS script, and having the Javascript add the "Show More/Show Less" toggle button. The issue with this approach was that the toggle button would be present regardless of the length of the row height for each cell in the 3rd column.